# Problems with Rust Enum

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching

I can't seem to get my Match Expression to work. Looking at it, It seems the same as other examples I've looked at.

```
fn draw(board: BoardType) {
    let board = match board{
        BoardType::B3x3(board, _) => board,
        BoardType::B4x4(board, _) => board
    };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum BoardType {
    B3x3([[Space; 3]; 3], (i8, i8)),
    B4x4([[Space; 4]; 4], (i8, i8)),
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
enum Space {
    Blank,
    X,
    O,
    Blocked,
}
```

```
BoardType::B4x4(board,_) => board
                            ^^^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 3 elements, found one with 4 elements
```

I don't really understand why this isn't working.

Comment: You need to match on *something*. It should be `match board { ...`

Comment: That said, you still cannot return `board` from your two match arms since they are of different types. But that's for another time

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I could handle each one individually with if let syntax?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure what your goal is in the `draw` method, so it's hard to say

Comment: My end goal is to make a game of Tic Tac Toe and use a minimax algorithm to make an AI. I eventually want it to be able to handle 3 dimensions, with a width of both 3 and 4. I thought an enum would be a good fit since there are 4 types of boards. now I'm not so sure enums are the way to go for this particular problem. the print method is just supposed to print the current state to the console. E.G. "X|O|X"

Comment: How you wish to handle this is up to you but the error is as I mentioned above. A 4x4 array is different from a 3x3. A match expression should evaluate to a specific type but it's confused because you're giving it 2 different types (4x4 vs 3x3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` expressions return a value. Even though you are not using that value in this code, the compiler needs to type-check the expression. However the two branches of the expression have different types: `[[Space; 3]; 3]` and `[[Space; 4]; 4]` respectively.

The error message is telling you that it expects the second branch to have the same type as the first.

Part of your problem is likely that your code is too simple, and isn't actually doing anything. Suppose you had functions for drawing these boards:

```
fn draw_3x3(board: [[Space; 3]; 3]) {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn draw_4x4(board: [[Space; 4]; 4]) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Then, when you use them, the branches will both have the same type (`()`), so the whole expression will type-check:

```
fn draw(board: BoardType) {
    let board = match board{
        BoardType::B3x3(board, _) => draw_3x3(board),
        BoardType::B4x4(board, _) => draw_4x4(board),
    };
}
```